# How to make a use of arrow function in es6 instead of bind method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

Previously i was using this to call my method in React JSX component, this method give me proper output

```
this.updateState.bind(this)
```

But when i replace above statement to

```
() => this.updateState(...this)
```

This doesn't give me output it returns undefined

Comment: why are you trying to spread `this` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should replace

```
 () => this.updateState(...this)
```

with

```
 (...args) => this.updateState(...args)
```

Arrow function inherit their context from their parent lexical scope.
When calling a function from an arrow function, it inherits from the "this" reference of the caller.

Answer (score 1):

In React you can bind the function to `this` in the constructor. `this` is undefined in your case as the function is not bound to it.

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props)
  this.updateState = this.updateState.bind(this)
}
```

Then you can use the function as normal. You don't want to bind the function to `this` every time you use it anyway.

And if you have the transform class properties plugin for Babel, you can automatically bind a class function by defining it like

```
updateState = () => {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Transform class properties**

```
updateState = () => {
  ...
}
```

Have a look on this: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties